# scale and transform img on hover

Tags: css, css-animations

So what I'm trying to make is a banner that has scale and transform like in this webpage: https://www.johannesfog.dk/
So the two landscape images overlap each other on hover.

This is how far I got:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image1">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src=""></script>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image1 {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image2 {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
    width: calc(100% - (0px * 2));
}

.container .image1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: translate(50%, 0%);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.container .image2:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Right now the img only transform.

Comment: In order to increase the chance of an answer, a working example would help a lot :)
However, The two images don't "overlap" each other, their containers are shrinking. And since the background image is set with the following CSS attributes `style="background: url(/globalassets/splash/splashtb1.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"`, the visibile part of the image is reduced while the image size is maintained. 
Long story short: checkout the [CSS Background Attribute and its Properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) and ask if something is unclear.